# What are the pros/cons of artifactoryPublish vs publish

Tags: gradle, artifactory

When using Artifactory with Gradle, one can use the `artifactory` plugin with the `artifactoryPublish` task, or one can use the `maven-publish` plugin with the `publish` task.

Both seem to do similar things, but by default `artifactoryPublish` does not seem to produce the `.sha512` files that the `publish` task does. Presumably there is some way to enable this in the `artifactory` plugin...

However, the real question is, why would someone prefer to use the `artifactory` plugin and `artifactoryPublish` task over the convention `maven-publish` plugin?

Answer (score 4):

You can use both to upload files to Artifactory.
The Gradle Artifactory plugin uses the `maven-publish` plugin. It extracts the Maven publications from the `maven-publish` plugin.

For the basic use case of just uploading a file to Artifactory, the `publish` task plugin will do the work. However, using the `artifactoryPublish` task you'll get some extra benefits such as:

1. [Build information](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Build+Integration) - after uploading the files, the Artifactory plugin generates and uploads information about the artifacts, dependencies, and rigorous information on your environment.
2. Add properties to uploaded artifacts.
3. Checksum deploy - before uploading a file, the Artifactory plugin checks whether the artifact exists in Artifactory. This feature enables also reproducible builds. See discussion in https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/issues/341. There is also a security benefit using this feature by allowing the deployer to not possess `Delete/Overwrite` permission in Artifactory.
4. Exclude artifacts from uploading.
5. Upload files using a built-in producer-consumer algorithm - publication with multiple files will be uploaded in parallel.
6. Maintenance by JFrog.
7. More...

To sum it up, the Artifactory plugin's expertise is to upload files to Artifactory. With the Artifactory plugin, you should get [reproducible builds](https://reproducible-builds.org/) and faster uploads.

For more information:

1. [Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin)
2. [Working with Gradle](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Working+with+Gradle)
3. [Source code](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/tree/master/build-info-extractor-gradle/src/main/groovy/org/jfrog/gradle/plugin/artifactory)